# JQuery advice needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need a simple form with radio buttons or pull downs, that returns a different message and link depending on the answer.

I don't want to save the data, but just to display based on the answer.

Is that we can do in JQuery..?

If anyone knows, please explain..

Comment: actually I didnt begin with code can you show me some examples regarding my requirement..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code example on [jquery's website for the change function](http://api.jquery.com/change/) is what you want, it registers a change handler, checks the value of the selected item, then changes the content of a div depending on your selection.